# In Terraform, can i have variables in Data Sources?

Tags: terraform

i will like to know if I can use variables while calling Data sources in terraform:

Instead of having:

**data.terraform_remote_state.dev_vpc**

I want to have a variable call dev like:

**data.terraform_remote_state.${var.stage}_vpc**

I tried to use the variable as it is above but got the error:

**Error: Invalid attribute name**

**on locals.tf line 21, in locals:**

**21:     for n in data.terraform_remote_state.${var.stage}_vpc :**

**An attribute name is required after a dot.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question here is how to have a resource or data name with a variable. This is not where you would want to place a variable. If you want to separate a data by environment lifecycle, then you can use workspaces, module declarations, filter arguments etc. to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't template an identifier like that, but there are a few other ways you could do it.

### Use a variable in the remote state definition:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "rs" {
  backend = "local"
  config = {
    path = local.remote_path
  }
}
```

This is a little simpler, and lets you template in your remote config using config files, locals, or variables as you want.

### Define multiple remote states, and index:

```
locals {
  remote_paths = { dev = "./dev/terraform.tfstate", prod = "./prod/terraform.tfstate" }
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "rs" {
  for_each = local.remote_paths
  backend = "local"
  config = {
    path = each.value
  }
}
```

You can now reference dev and prod at `data.terraform_remote_state.rs["dev"]` or `data.terraform_remote_state.rs["prod"]`

Comment: thank you so much for your feedback, I will give it a go now.

Comment: Have a look to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75147949/how-can-i-use-variables-in-terraform-module-when-call-data-resources#75149901

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
locals {
    stage_map = {
        ¨variable1 name¨ = data.terraform_remote_state.variable1_value
        ¨variable2 name¨ = data.terraform_remote_state.variable2_value
    }
}

resource "xxxx" "this" {
    name = var.scp_name
    content = local.stage_map[var.stage]
}
```