# How can I use variables in terraform module when call data/resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I got a basic Terraform code where the main.tf call a module to create an AWS organization policy.

** main.tf **

```
module "SCP-L2-RegionRestriction" {
  source        = "github.com/awsmodulecode/scps.git"
  scp_name      = "SCP-L2-RegionRestriction"
}
```

** module **

```
resource "aws_organizations_policy" "SCP-L2-RegionRestriction" {
  name    = var.scp_name
  content = data.aws_iam_policy_document."${var.scp.name}".json
}
```

** variables.tf **

```
variable "scp_name" {
  description = "Policy name."
}
```

** The error **

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid attribute name
│ 
│ On .terraform/modules/SCP-L2-RegionRestriction/main.tf line 4: An attribute name is required after a dot.
╵
```

Is there a way to manage variable `"${var.scp.name}"` inside of a data call?

This is my data source content:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "scp_fulladmin_deny" {
    statement {
            actions = ["*"]
            resources = ["*"]
            effect = "Deny"
            }
}
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "scp_fulladmin_allow" {
    statement {
            actions = ["*"]
            resources = ["*"]
            effect = "Allow"
            }
}
```

Comment: You cannot do that. The data source name has to be defined with a logical name prior to running apply, it gets evaluated prior to creating resources, so interpolation will not work. If you add the policy data source, then someone might be able to give you an answer.

Comment: Check out this stackoverflow question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69840638/in-terraform-can-i-have-variables-in-data-sources

Comment: The linked example is not valid for my code a this is a different resource. I need a way to use one module for multiple policies otherwise a module for each policy I need to create. I was thinking on something like this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use variables to reference data or resources; but you can do something like this:

```
locals {
    policy_map = {
        scp_fulladmin_deny = data.aws_iam_policy_document.scp_fulladmin_deny.json,
        scp_fulladmin_allow = data.aws_iam_policy_document.scp_fulladmin_allow.json,
    }
}

resource "aws_organizations_policy" "this" {
    name = var.scp_name
    content = local.policy_map[var.scp_name]
}
```